# Sums of odd numbers in array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get the sum of the odd numbers in an array. I am trying to write a method `odd_sums` that accepts an array of numbers, and return the sum of the odd numbers in it.

```
odd_sum([5,4,6,13,1]) # => 19
odd_sum([10,2,11,3]) # => 14
odd_sum([8,18]) # => 0
```

I got the odd numbers in the array:

```
def odd_sum(a.)
  new_arr = []
  i = 0
  while i < a.length
    if a.[i] % 2!=0
      new_arr << a.[i]
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return new_arr
end
```

But I cannot get the sum of the odd numbers. Please help me.

Comment: Your function isn't adding any if the numbers. Looks like it's just building another array. Why is the argument `a.` and not just `a`?

Answer (score 11):

I suggest:

```
a = [5, 4, 6, 13, 1]

a.select(&:odd?).sum
#=> 19
```

Comment: According to [my benchmark](https://gist.github.com/maxcal/b4caed823d66b6abc2996f4378ef9b5f) this is actually faster than sum with a block. Go figure.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to make more than one pass through the array or create a temporary array.

```
def odd_sum(arr)
  arr.sum { |n| n.odd? ? n : 0 }
end

odd_sum([5,4,6,13,1]) #=> 19
odd_sum([10,2,11,3])  #=> 14
odd_sum([8,18])       #=>  0
```

Comment: Interestingly `arr.select(&:odd?).sum` is faster according to my [simple benchmark](https://gist.github.com/maxcal/b4caed823d66b6abc2996f4378ef9b5f).

Comment: @max, I can't say I'm surprised, as `sum` is undoubtedly very fast. (For fun, try `arr.sum` in your benchmark.) There is still he matter of the creation of a temporary array, but arguably `arr.select(&:odd?).sum` also reads better.

Comment: `arr = Array.new(1000_0000) { rand(1...20) }` hangs in my console... why?

Comment: @lacostenycoder, I don't know. Computing 10 million random numbers, and making space for them, doesn't seem like a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

Correcting the syntax and using a simple integer to store the sum (you don't need a storage-array).

```
def odd_sum(a)
  sum = 0         
  i = 0
  while i < a.length
    if a[i] % 2 != 0
      sum += a[i]
    end
  i += 1
  end
  return sum      #return can be omitted
end

puts odd_sum([1, 2, 3, 4]) # 4
```

Look at the other answers to learn how to use more Ruby-like code.

Answer (score 2):

write this code

```
a=[5,4,6,13,1]

puts a.select{|x|x.odd?}.sum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.select` along with `.sum`  which are methods of [Enumerable class](https://ruby-doc.com/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle) and [Array class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-select)

```
def odd_sum(arr)
  arr.select{|i| i % 2 == 0}.sum
end
```

# but since you're dealing with an array of integers you can use `.odd?` wich does this same thing as `i % 2 == 0` as shown by @Rajagopalan answer

```
def odd_sum(arr)
  arr.select{|i| i.odd? }.sum
  #or the shorthand version: arr.select(&:odd?).sum
end
```

Alternative syntax where you can pass a block to `.sum` Here we subtract the number from sum if it is even. This is a bit less readable but is valid syntax and is actually the less efficient for your use case.  See benchmarks.

```
def odd_sum(arr)
  arr.sum {|i| i.odd? ? i : 0}
end
```

#### Benchmarks based on @max 's comment on other answer posted.

```
arr = Array.new(1_00000){rand(1..200)}

puts Benchmark.measure{arr.select(&:odd?).sum}
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.005207)

puts Benchmark.measure{arr.sum{|n|n.odd? ? n : 0}}
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.006952)
```

Comment: @ElgunQuliyev see updated answer which gives benchmark for fastest method

Comment: I get different benchmarks results for an array with random numbers instead of `100000.times` which is sequential which may be affecting the outcome. `a.sum {|i| i.even? ? i - i : i}` is slower.

Comment: `i-i` ? Why not just 0 ?

Comment: @steenslag updated my answer and thanks to max  benchmarks also updated.